# SetValue on PropertyInfo instance error "Object does not match target type" c#

Tags: c#, reflection, setvalue

Been using a Copy method with this code in it in various places in previous projects (to deal with objects that have same named properties but do not derive from a common base class or implement a common interface).

New place of work, new codebase - now it's failing at the SetValue with "Object does not match target type" even on very simple examples... and it worked last week....

```
    public static void Copy(object fromObj, object toObj)
    {   
        Type fromObjectType = fromObj.GetType();
        Type toObjectType = toObj.GetType();

        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo fromProperty in 
            fromObjectType.GetProperties())
        {
            if (fromProperty.CanRead)
            {
                string propertyName = fromProperty.Name;
                Type propertyType = fromProperty.PropertyType;

                System.Reflection.PropertyInfo toProperty = 
                    toObjectType.GetProperty(propertyName);

                Type toPropertyType = toProperty.PropertyType;

                if (toProperty != null && toProperty.CanWrite)
                {
                    object fromValue = fromProperty.GetValue(fromObj,null);
                    toProperty.SetValue(toProperty,fromValue,null);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class test
    {
        private int val;
        private string desc;

        public int Val { get { return val; } set { val = value; } }

        public string Desc { get { return desc; } set { desc = value; } }

    }

    private void TestIt()
    {
        test testo = new test();
        testo.Val = 2;
        testo.Desc = "TWO";

        test g = new test();

        Copy(testo,g);

    }
```

Hopefully someone can point out where I am being daft???

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try:

```
toProperty.SetValue(toObj,fromValue,null);
```

You are trying to pass in the property (`toProperty`) as the target object, instead of `toObj`. For info, if you are doing lots of this, maybe consider [HyperDescriptor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HyperDescriptor/), which can vastly reduce the reflection cost.

Comment: D'oh! that's the bug I fixed the LAST time I wrote it - and forgot to check this time...

Answer (score 13):

Should be

```
toProperty.SetValue(toObj,fromValue,null);
```